# IIS not returning content if .html file contains no markup

Tags: html, iis, filter

Google sent me file to put on my website in order for me to validate that I have control of the domain: *google123456789.html*. The file contains no markup:

```
google-site-verification: google123456789.html
```

When I try to access the URL, I just get a 200 response but no payload. Why?

**Troubleshooting**

If I add `<html>...</html>` tags to the payload is downloaded...but the Google verification fails, probably because the file content isn't exactly what it expects.

If I change the file to be `.txt`, the payload is downloaded...but the Google verification fails because the URL of the file isn't what it's expecting.

Comment: Do you have it in a public domain? Can you share the URL you are accessing? In the other hand, if this method is giving you problems you could try with the tag method instead of uploading the file.

Comment: It's https://qa.autoanything.net/google77ad566de3a449b8.html. I'd rather not add extra tags to our QA environment. Uploading a simple HTML file seemed like a simple enough thing to do!